# Private listing for Google marketplace App

Tags: php, google-apps-marketplace

I published Google Marketplace App and made Visibility option set to Private.

I created a group and added my Google for Work user.

However if i login to my Google for Work account then i am not finding the App.

I have searched in For yourdomain.com section of the Google Apps Marketplace but the app is still not visible.

The App status is showing as 'Published to Testers'. I am trying to publish an app to a few trusted testers before fully releasing. Is there anything that i need to do.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Based from [Access Marketplace apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981), most apps are available immediately after deployment. In some cases, **there may be a delay of up to 24 hours before the application is displayed**.

Comment: Its been more than 36 hours the app has been published. I logged in to my Google for Work account, clicked on Apps, clicked on Marketplace Apps and if i search the App in 'All' or 'For your domain' only option, then also i am not finding it. Please help

Comment: Could you provide screenshot what options you have enabled while listing you app